# Draw icons over video seekbar in android

Tags: android, video, android-seekbar

I have a requirement to draw a elevated seekbar, with ups and downs and also have icons drawn over it.

Seekbar is highlighted with red circle.
If elevation is not possible, I like to draw a linear seekbar, but I need to draw the icons, and click on the icons need to show some view.

I have searched, but couldn't find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a custom view with transparent background and place it above your video, here is a manual https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components
Custom view will provide you with [canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) where you can draw whatever you want similar to https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing

Comment: I have created a linearlayout and placed over the seekbar, works fine. But I have some images, inside the LinearLayout, that images should be placed on particular second of the seekbar, for ex I need to show image at 5 sec, 10sec, 5000sec of the video, it may vary. My issues is placing the image where the seekbar thumb meets that particular second. Note, the images should be loaded initially, not when the seekbar thumb reach the particular time. Let the seekbar be a straight line.

Comment: @Manikandan did you find a solution?